# Why I still need to entry the pass after I hava added my key to the server?

Tags: ssh, redhat

I add my key to the server(authorized_keys), but i still need to entry the pass each time, and there

is no known_hosts files. i do not know why , who can help me ? thanks!

Comment: I've got to ask: Did you set a passphrase on the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check-out if you are missing any step for key based ssh authentication, from the following link.

http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~ryan/tech/ssh-no-password.html

if still not working, try to share your findings.